# Getting malformed url route-flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to add two numbers and display it in a new html page,

the code follows
     from flask import Flask,render_template,request

```
app=Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def index(name='Priya'):
    name=request.args.get('name',name)

    return "I am happy,{}".format(name)



@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<float :num2>')
@app.route('/add/<float:num1>/<float :num2>')
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<int :num2>')
@app.route('/add/<float:num1>/<int :num2>')
def add(num1,num2):
    #return str(num1+num2)
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <html> 
    <head><title>Addition game! </title></head><body>
    <h1>

    {}+{} = {}</body></html>""".format(num1,num2,num1+num2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<float :num2>')
```

contains a space which shouldn't be there

```
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<float:num2>')
```

is the correct syntax